# Dialog "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" shows just once in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, dialog, onbeforeunload

**Issue:**

To show the dialog (http://prntscr.com/co2um0) I use javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dialog</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
      return false;
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The dialog will not be shown second time (on current domain during the session) if I click "Leave Page".

The dialog will be shown second time (on current domain during the session) if I click "Stay on Page".

The dialog doesn't have a checkbox like "Don't show again".

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Add javascript to the page A:
2. Open page A in Safari;
3. Try to go out from the page A;
4. You see dialog "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
5. Click button "Leave Page";
6. Go back to the page A;
   7.Try to go out from the page A;
7. You don't see the dialog "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";

**Expected Results:**

8. You see the dialog "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"

**Actual Results:**

8. You don't see the dialog "Are you sure you want to leave this page?".

**Reprodused on:**

OS X 10.11.6
Safari 9.1.2

**Notes:**

Some other browsers has checkbox like "Do not show this message again" in the dialogs (alert dialog for example) when it is shown second time.

Comment: Any updates? I'm struggling with this too. I found a bug report about this: http://www.openradar.me/28814642 that was marked as a duplicate of another issue, but I'm unable to access the original issue?